# Deserializing JSON to List<> is not working in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

This is the JSON i got from stream, and converted to string.

```
"{\"data\":[{\"thread_id\":\"1111155552222\",\"recipients\":[123123,456456],\"message_count\":2100},{\"thread_id\":\"1111155553333\",\"recipients\":[123124,456457],\"message_count\":4851},{\"thread_id\":\"1111155554444\",\"recipients\":[123125,456458],\"message_count\":435}]}"
```

---

```
public class DataContainer
{
    List<data> data { get; set; }
}

public class data
{
    public string thread_id { get; set; }
    public long[] recipients { get; set; }
    public int message_count { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

DataContainer data = ser.Deserialize<DataContainer>(json);
```

I am getting null at data, it does not seem to get deserialize. amateur in json. getting headache with this already.

Thanks!

---

Getting the JSON string

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, encode);
string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: You might want to tag this with C#. It will make it easier for the appropriate people to see your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your "***JSON you got from stream and converted to string***" has been serialized twice.

ASP.NET automatically JSON serializes your service methods’ responses, even if their result is an object or collection of objects

You should be able to use it directly without having to serialize/deserialize it.

Something like:

```
//Assuming GetJson() returns a JSON string, which you can use directly 
DataContainer data = GetJson();
```

Check this: http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Also this: [Reading from JSON, data not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362633/reading-from-json-data-not-displayed)

Comment: I have sorted out the issue by creating a JObject, and deserialize it.

    `JObject dataa = JObject.Parse(json);
    data[] data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<data[]>(dataa["data"].ToString());`